# How to add two sets of time? e.g 00:10:10 + 00:00:20 = 00:10:30

Tags: c#, winforms

The following code is how to get the difference between two sets of time . . .But How about Addition?
Please help . . .

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dFrom;
        DateTime dTo;
        string sDateFrom = "00:10:38";
        string sDateTo = "00:00:04";
        if (DateTime.TryParse(sDateFrom, out dFrom) && DateTime.TryParse(sDateTo, out dTo))
        {
            TimeSpan TS = dFrom - dTo;
            int hour = TS.Hours;
            int mins = TS.Minutes;
            int secs = TS.Seconds;
  string timeDiff = hour.ToString("00") + ":" + mins.ToString("00") + ":" +  secs.ToString("00");
            textBox1.Text = timeDiff;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at `DateTime.Add`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.add%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks, Gonna try this link for the moment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like `TimeSpans` would be better suited here:

```
TimeSpan tsFrom;
TimeSpan tsTo;

string sFrom = "00:10:38";
string sTo = "00:00:04";

if (TimeSpan.TryParse(sFrom, out tsFrom) && TimeSpan.TryParse(sTo, out tsTo))
{
    TimeSpan ts = tsFrom + tsTo; // 00:10:42
}
```